# How to add image into scroll view and scroll view add into table cell?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Hi I am writing a tutorial similar to Pulse news app (http://www.pulse.me/) I am not sure how to make the scrolling on the table cell. I see, there are scroll on each table cell in this app + image items.

I really have no idea how to start this. Does anyone do this scroll + image in a table cell before? Please help me out, if there is code example is even greater.

Thanks in advance